# How to use nvidia graphics for display to better screen resolution

Tags: 16.04, display-resolution, monitor, grub-efi, nvidia-geforce

I finally was able of installing cuda9.2 (nvidia 396 64bit) using the run files. Had to add `--no-opengl-files` to avoid login loop issue.

However the screen resolution is not good. I tried changing it directly on grub with command `GRUB_GFXMODE=1600x1200` and `nomodeset` flag but it seems not matching my screen resolution (1920x1080). This results to a bit fuzz display.

`videoinfo` grub command does not list any resolution matching my hardware.

Should I try ammending `xorg.conf` file?

P.S the nvidia card is a GTX 1080ti.

Answer (score 0):

I was finally able of obtaining the resolution I wanted. To do so I performed the following:

1. First I insured that the nvidia slot is in uefi mode. I did so from the motherboard bios.
2. Then I executed the following command line 
   `nvidia-xconfig --enable-all-gpus --separate-x-screens`
   following a suggestion I found in https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/769851/multi-nvidia-gpus-and-xorg-conf-how-to-account-for-pci-bus-busid-change-/

Am even able now of using NVIDIA X Server Settings.